# Data connection takes number and creates a text

Tags: excel, connection

I exported an xlsx workbook from SAS (workbookA.xlsx).  I want to use this data in another workbook that will house a table (workbookB.xlsx).

When I open woorkbookA I can change column D from "General" formatting to a "Percentage" and the % sign shows up as expected.

When I create the data connection in woorkbookB from workbookA, and create a table, I can format all columns except for column D. When I change column D from "General" formatting to a "Percentage" nothing happens, which after researching means that it's stored as a text.  How does it change from a general format form workbook A to a text format in workbookB?  I haven't found this issue anywhere else on the internet.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: How exactly did you create the connection?

Comment: I went to  Data "Existing Connections" and then browsed for the file, found the file, clicked "Open", selected the table, clicked the "Table" radio button to view the data as a table in the workbook and then clicked "ok"